# Where can I find a paper that has been cited multiple times but only ever appears as a citation?

Tags: publications, literature-search, databases

I'm doing an assignment on early warning score (EWS) systems as part of a postgraduate diploma in Medical Technologies.

The progenitor of the system is cited in several papers as Morgan et al.

Morgan, R.J.M., Williams, F. and Wright, M.M., 1997. An early warning scoring system for detecting developing critical illness. Clin Intensive Care, 8(2), p.100.

However, it appears everywhere I look there is no abstract let alone a full text. For example; https://www.scienceopen.com/document?vid=28251d22-8476-40a6-916d-1a34796816e4

Clin, Intensive Care does not seem to show the contents:

https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/icic20/8/2?nav=tocList

My university offers some access to tandf but does not seem to give access to the issue of this journal.

Does anyone know where I can find awkward papers such as the above?

Comment: From the title, this sounds like it's asking about "apocryphal papers".  I know at least a few preprints that were regularly cited but never appeared.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You won't be able to find the full text of this particular article because it doesn't exist!

The work was actually a poster presentation at the *Intensive Care Society*'s Spring 1997 meeting. The journal merely reprinted the program and abstracts of the presentation. If you follow the OP's link above to Volume 8, Issue 2 of *Clinical Intensive Care*, the last entry in the Table of Contents is "Abstracts – Intensive Care Society Spring Meeting, May 1997." That "article" has its own table of contents, one of which was the abstract.

In fact, the journal has a (very small) reproduction of the poster on p. 100.  This one is mostly text, but I imagine that poster reprints weren't slated for digitization since they'd be harder to put into a standard format.

[image: Poster: An early warning scoring system for detecting developing critical illness.]

The full table of contents may not show up if your institution doesn't subscribe the journal. However, @SeanJ reports that you can find a link to it under "Related Research -> People also read."

[image]

Comment: brilliant!  Any chance you could list the methodology as to how you discovered the poster so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: Please clarify "slated for digitization".

Comment: It's actually right at OP's link. The last entry in the Table of Contents is "Abstracts – Intensive Care Society Spring Meeting, May 1997." That "article" has its own table of contents, one of which was the abstract.

Comment: For something as popular as this seems to have been, I would think the author would have fleshed it out for the peer reviewed literature.  I found author RJ Morgan here [In defence of early warning scores](https://www.bjanaesthesia.org/article/S0007-0912(17)34707-4/fulltext) but on referring to his work he cites the same poster!  I guess they never did write it up.

Comment: @RosieF From the era, this was (probably) printed first and digitized later. Consequently, the journal hasn't bothered to make individual abstracts/posters searchable: posters are tricky to OCR and the list of oral presentations isn't that useful a quarter-century later.

Comment: @Matt I understand that, but please could you clarify in your answer what you meant by your phrase "slated for digitization".

Comment: @Willk - indeed, they haven't written it up, but do show a propensity to write commentary and letters to the editor pointing out that their work should be cited. Pretty lame of them, frankly...

Comment: @RosieF **slate** *verb* **2:** to designate (someone or something) for a specified purpose or action occurring especially at a fixed time

Comment: Sorry, @RosieF--I didn't realize you meant the actual word: I meant it in the sense hobbs wrote: picked, chosen, selected, etc.

Answer (score 85):

Ask your librarian. They are really (*really*) good at finding these articles.

That said, the article you're looking for isn't actually an article. [This link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3109/tcic.8.2.93.110) indicates it's actually a poster at the Intensive Care Society Spring Meeting, 1997. Your best bet might be to check for that conference's proceedings, if there is one, which again is something your librarian will be very able to help with.

Comment: Studying remotely but have sent them a request (no response).  Would be nice to know what they do as then I could do it without having to bother them all the time and have waiting delays.

Comment: @SeanJ Don't worry about bothering a librarian to do some research - it's their job and it seems that most who do it do it specifically because they love it.

Comment: @BryanKrause and others. The life of a librarian would be pretty dull if they never got a challenge. The research librarian at my former employer actually advertised her services to the department.

Comment: And one can do a search on the lead author, limiting the time to plus/minus a year or so to see if it got published in some journal eventually.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: *because they love it* --- Maybe I should have been a librarian? See [this search](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/12807/264) and [this other search](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5681/264). (Note: The various searches I describe were done without any paywall or library access capability.)

Comment: Maybe some librarians love it but so far, I've had no response from the university library.  I've heard good things about them but it doesn't help me if they don't answer my request.  Thanks for the link, really helpful!

Comment: @SeanJ if it's only been a few hours, give them some time, especially if you're in different timezones. They could e.g. be waiting for a response themselves (e.g. if they're requesting the document from another library via an interlibrary loan).

Comment: Interestingly, Web Of Science yields nothing until 2000,  ANAESTHESIA 55 (4) , pp.391-392, a note that also references the item you list, which is not available on-line through my library services. Quite an interesting situation... See also from 1997 BRITISH JOURNAL OF ANAESTHESIA 99 (5) , pp.747-748 which is also a note to the editor again referencing the original item. Odd that they never seem to have written an actual journal article...

Comment: Librarians "are really (really) good" period! Librarians make the world go 'round, and *reference librarians* keep it in orbit around the Sun.

Comment: If it is a conference poster, chances are (depending on the conference) that it is not reprinted in the proceedings (although then how come people cite it..). Anyway: if the librarian cannot find a copy, dont hesitate to write to the author if they can send you a copy.

Comment: @Allure Fwiw, still no response from the library

Answer (score 12):

In general, for journals that have not been digitized or at least are unavailable in the databases you have access to, you can try to track down a print copy of the journal. For instance, I would search *Clinical Intensive Care* in your university's library site. If that turns up nothing, run the same search on [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/), which will let you see which major libraries have copies of the journal, after which you could visit those libraries' sites to confirm the right volume and issue are accessible.

If you're in the US, your library may also participate in Interlibrary Loan, which would allow them to make a request for materials from another library. Commonly, short articles or excerpts can be scanned and delivered digitally, though actual practice may differ from library to library.

Contacting research librarians (as Allure mentions) is also a good step. No matter what you try, they may have another tool or bit of experience that can help you track a source down.

Comment: That is a good approach. I've sometimes found that research librarians at institutions that happen to have the print copy can be very responsive and helpful. And of course, other countries also have various systems in place for requesting materials from other libraries.

Answer (score 9):

You could try to find the authors email, affiliation, ResearchGate, etc (although it may have changed since 1997) and try to email them directly for a copy of the poster (maybe not likely for a 1997 poster) or a copy of the original abstract submitted. Most authors are happy to share this information.

This approach might not work well for something 25 years old, but would be really useful for more recent, similar things that are conference presentations or posters.

Comment: This [letter-to-the-editor](https://www.bmj.com/content/369/bmj.m1501/rapid-responses) in 2020 by one of the authors includes both email addresses.

Comment: docm at blueyonder.co.uk

https://academic.oup.com/bja/article/99/5/747/257789?login=false

Comment: This is a good general strategy, and you can also try emailing people who cited the work, if they discussed it in any depth.

Answer (score 5):

Some libraries have a catalog that you can try.

For instance, the university libraries of Germany have a joint catalog, in which your journal can be found. They even have a reference to the electronic version, but they also show which university libraries have which issues on the shelves. Perhaps in Ireland, there is something similar.

If you follow the links, you get the information that page 100 of the issue that your paper is in seems to be *part* of the article "Abstracts – Intensive Care Society Spring Meeting, May 1997", which tells you why you don't find an abstract -- this is a collection of abstracts, so a single abstract for it would not make sense (or would just say in which context the presentations took place).

If you don't get access through your institution, ask a librarian of the library of your institution. Perhaps you can make a inter-library loan or something like that to obtain the paper.

Comment: "this is a collection of abstract(s), so a single abstract for it would not make sense" - The citation is not for the collection of abstracts, it's a citation for a single abstract in the collection. OP would be looking for the text of that abstract; probably the full presentation is not available if this was an abstract for a poster presentation or oral presentation given in person at the conference.

Comment: @BryanKrause Exactly, this is why he doesn't find an abstract for "Morgan, R.J.M., Williams, F. and Wright, M.M., 1997. An early warning scoring system for detecting developing critical illness. Clin Intensive Care, 8(2), p.100." - it's a citation to a part of the journal's item.

Comment: I suspect we're a bit talking around each other, but... OP doesn't want "an abstract for" "Abstracts – Intensive Care Society Spring Meeting, May 1997", OP wants the abstract "Morgan, R.J.M., Williams, F. and Wright, M.M., 1997. An early warning scoring system for detecting developing critical illness. Clin Intensive Care, 8(2), p.100." - it's still an abstract no matter how it is published.

Answer (score 5):

Ask the authors directly. This letter in the BMJ has two of the authors email addresses. Will an intensivist have a copy of a 25 year old poster in their portfolio? Let us know if you find out!

https://www.bmj.com/content/369/bmj.m1501/rapid-responses